# How can I get the current filesystem location in a C# implementation of IArgumentCompleter?

Tags: c#, powershell, autocomplete

I am implementing a custom argument completer in C#, inheriting from IArgumentCompleter. In `CompleteArgument`, I try to do the equivalent of

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation.ProviderPath
```

I tried

```
Runspace.DefaultRunspace.SessionStateProxy.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation.Path
```

but that throws an exception telling me a pipeline is already running.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `EngineIntrinsics ei; using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) { ei = ps.AddScript("$ExecutionContext").Invoke<EngineIntrinsics>()[0] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @PetSerAl is an answer:

```
string pwd;
EngineIntrinsics ei; 
using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) 
{ 
    ei = ps.AddScript("$ExecutionContext").Invoke<EngineIntrinsics>()[0] 
    pwd = ei.SessionState.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation.ProviderPath
}
```